# Invalid encoding for redirected output

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

OS Windows, C#.
I have a problem with output encoding.

```
App.Document doc = cad.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
if (doc != null)
    doc.Editor.WriteMessage("\nProcess started. Please, wait...\n");
String exeName = Path.Combine(curDir, "recovery");
Process proc = new Process();            
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
// info.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
info.StandardOutputEncoding = Console.OutputEncoding;
info.FileName = exeName;
info.Arguments = String.Format("{0} -clear", @"%zipDir%\acad_R17.2.zip");
proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.Start();
String outputText = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
proc.WaitForExit();
if (doc != null) {
    doc.Editor.WriteMessage(outputText);
    doc.Editor.WriteMessage(Environment.NewLine);                
    doc.Editor.WriteMessage("Operation is complete.");
    doc.Editor.WriteMessage(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Output result:

> recovery; (c) Andrey Bushman, 2013
>
> ЋЎа Ў®вЄ  Є в «®Ј  "%acad_R17.2%". ќ«Ґ¬Ґ­в: AutoCAD 2009/; –Ґ«Ґў®©
>   Є в «®Ј: C:\Program Files\Autodesk; ЋиЁЎЄ : ЋвЄ § ­® ў ¤®бвгЇҐ Ї® ЇгвЁ
>   "acad.CUI". ЋЎа Ў®вЄ  Є в «®Ј  "%rmb_acad_R17.2%". ЋЎа Ў®вЄ  Є в «®Ј 
>   "%local_acad_R17.2%". ЋЎа Ў®вЄ  Є в «®Ј  "%allUsers_acad_R17.2%".
>   ЋЎа Ў®вЄ  Є в «®Ј  "%shared_acad_R17.2%". ќ«Ґ¬Ґ­в: Autodesk Shared/;
>   –Ґ«Ґў®© Є в «®Ј: C:\Program Files\Common Files; ЋиЁЎЄ : ЋвЄ § ­® ў
>   ¤®бвгЇҐ Ї® ЇгвЁ "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\".
>   ЋЎа Ў®вЄ  Є в «®Ј  "%ext_acad_R17.2%".

But if I launch recovery.exe through the cmd.exe, in the console I see the correct text. How can I get the valid text through my code?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers. Two variants:

1. [GetOEMCP](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getoemcp)
2. [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.oemcodepage.aspx)

Both work fine.